# Yii2 checkboxlist broken down into categories (nested sets)

Tags: php, yii2, checkboxlist, nested-sets, active-form

I seem to be having some trouble creating a form input that allows checkboxlists and nested sets to work together.

What I'd like, is something exactly like what bookbub does:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHmD0.jpg

Right now in my database I have it structured as follows:

```
Category table
    - id
    - name
    - parent_id
```

Basically, my idea is to display everything on the _form that has parent_id as null as a heading (no checkbox) and everything that has a parent_id as a checkbox under the appropriate heading.

However, the only solution that I can get that's close doesn't seem to allow me to have checkboxes already checked if we're updating a user's preferences. It does however display things exactly how I would like. Here's what I have so far:

ProfileReader's (ProfileReader is my model that extends users to hold their preferences) _form:

```
<?php
$primaryCategories = (new Category)->getPrimaryCategories();
//$selectedCategories = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($model->categories, 'id', 'name');
foreach ($primaryCategories as $pc) {
  echo '<p>'.$pc->name.'</p>';
  if ($pc->subCategories) {

    //the following never fully worked. It doesn't automatically check the boxes for relations that
    //are already setup. You need to somehow use $model->categories[#] and 'id' for that to work
    //echo $form->field($model->categories[#], 'id')->label(false)
    echo $form->field($pc, 'subCategories[' . $pc->id . '][]')->label(false)
              ->checkboxList(yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($pc->subCategories, 'id', 'name'),
                  ['separator' => '<p>']);
  }
}
?>
```

ProfileReaderController:

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
    $model = $this->findModel(\Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
    if ($model == null) {
      $model = new ProfileReader();
      $model->user_id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

      //link the categories to the pen name
      $categories = Yii::$app->request->post()['Category']['subCategories'];
      $model->unlinkAll('categories', true);
      foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category) 
          foreach ($category as $c) {
            $c = (new Category)->findOne($c);
            $model->link('categories', $c);
          }
      }

      return $this->redirect(['update']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

ProfileReader:

```
public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id'])
      ->viaTable('user_category', ['user_id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

Does anyone have any clue how I can make this work? Is it even possible in Yii2 with activeform?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after many hours I finally figured it out. Posting my resulting code here so that it may help someone else. Don't ask me to explain it as I don't fully get it myself :P

It might also be a good idea to do some testing on it too before throwing it into a live environment, I haven't done any yet.

update action:

```
/**
 * Updates an existing ProfileReader model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionUpdate()
{
    $model = $this->findModel(\Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
    if ($model == null) {
      $model = new ProfileReader();
      $model->user_id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

      //unlink the categories first to avoid duplicates
      $model->unlinkAll('categories', true);
      //link the categories to the pen name
      foreach ($model->categoriesArray as $pc) {
        if ($pc) {
          foreach ($pc as $sc) {
            $sc = (new Category)->findOne($sc);
            $model->link('categories', $sc);
          }
        }
      }

      return $this->redirect(['update']);
    } else {

      //get the categories and separate them into groups based on parent_id
      foreach ($model->categories as $c) {
        $model->categoriesArray[$c->parent_id][] = $c;
      }

      return $this->render('update', [
          'model' => $model,
      ]);
    }
}
```

ProfileReader model (had to add a variable):

public $categoriesArray;

_form:

```
<label class="control-label">Categories</label>
<?php
$allCategories = (new Category)->getOrderedCategories();
foreach ($allCategories as $pc) {
  echo '<p>'.$pc['name'].'</p>';
    echo $form->field($model, 'categoriesArray['.$pc['id'].'][]')->label(false)
              ->checkboxList(yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($pc['subCategories'], 'id', 'name'),
                  ['separator' => '<p>']);
}
?>
```